# How to Flip the Edges in 3ds max?

Tags: 3ds-max, games

is there any way how can I do this operation in 3ds max?
[image: Flip Edges]

Comment: HI and welcome. You might benefit from knowing that operating 3d software is not graphic design. So you might get an answer but it might take a very long time... See [this page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds-max) and read the note section.

Comment: I have a tool almost precisely like that in Modo - I'm unaware of such in 3DS, but that's probably because I'm not a big user of 3DS these days - I'm *sure* it must be in there... somewhere.